# PayPal JavaScript SDK: I can't set the amount value dynamically

Tags: javascript, paypal

I need to change `"value": 22` to the value of the variable `precioServicio` but I cannot change it.

```
var precioServicio = document.getElementById("precioServicio");

createOrder: function(data, actions) {
    return actions.order.create({
      purchase_units: [{"amount":{"currency_code":"USD","value":22}}] //PRECIO A PAGAR
    });
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the hardcoded number `22` with... `precioServicio` or `document.getElementById("precioServicio")`

Comment: It is the correct solution, but since you have not shown what you tried or the rest of the page there is nothing more we can advise.

Answer (score 0):

You can use purchase_units: [{"amount":{"currency_code":"USD","value":Number(precioServicio)}}]

Comment: This will work, although the conversion to number is unnecessary. String values are fine.